# PDF Figure doesn't show the Curve

Tags: graphics, pdf

I use Mac Numbers to produce my charts. I export them as PDF and put in my LaTeX file. But in the compiled LaTeX file, I see everything expect the curve. As an example, here is the figure I produced as PDF:

[image]

and it shows up in my LaTeX after compilation like this:

[image]

In your opinion, what is the problem?

Here is the source:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\title{Example}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

Here is a Figure.

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.69]{1.pdf}}
\caption{\label{fig:atak} ATA by Varying $k$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) hard to say. Would it be possible to (a) see a minimal example document that produces the problematic image, (b) the included image itself. (3) How exactly are you previewing this? Have you tried a different previewer?

Comment: This is how I put in my LateX:\begin{figure}[htpb]
 \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.35, keepaspectratio =
      true]{fig.pdf}}
\caption{My caption}
\end{figure}

Comment: Please update your question with that information, pluse, that is a sniplet, not a full minimal example, we cannot see which class you are using, which packages etc. Pelase provide that as well. Plus it would be beneficial to see the PDF.

Comment: As mentioned, we need to see that PDF.

Comment: Its an unsubmitted research paper and I can't post it online.

Comment: Then how are we suppose to help? And we are not taling about the entire article. Make a copy, remove anything irrelevant, and post that. I.e. make the shortest document possible that still compiles and show this error. I would guess that you do not even need any text in that document. In general preparing these minimal examples is a good learning tool for debugging LaTeX problems.

Comment: Added links to PDF and TEX. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: 'Works for me' if I download the image (PDF) your link to and include it in a minimal file (`\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}\includegraphics{1}\end{document}`) using pdfLaTeX in TeX Live 2014 (up to date today). PDFs both look OK in TeXworks and Adobe Reader (Win7).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a non-reproducible problem.